# Consultar dados com mascara - SQL Server

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29027c4/1

```
CREATE TABLE PATRIMONIO (
    NUM_PATRIMONIO VARCHAR(100),
    DESCRICAO_PATRIMONIO VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO PATRIMONIO 
VALUES ('HDT-2725','VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV'),
('HDT-2744','VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV'),
('HDT-2751','VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV'),
('HDT-2764','Fiat Palio Celebration 1.4 Fire Flex 8V 4p'),
('002376','Notebook Dell i5 8GB 1TB')
```

Com o seguinte select:

```
SELECT NUM_PATRIMONIO, DESCRICAO_PATRIMONIO FROM PATRIMONIO
```

Essa não é a estrutura completa da tabela, isso foi apenas um exemplo que trouxe de como os dados estão aparecendo. No momento, eles estão vindo assim:

```
NUM_PATRIMONIO  DESCRICAO_PATRIMONIO
HDT-2725        VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV
HDT-2744        VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV
HDT-2751        VW/GOL 1.0 GER IV
HDT-2764        Fiat Palio Celebration 1.4 Fire Flex 8V 4p
002376          Notebook Dell i5 8GB 1TB
```

E eu preciso que o retorno seja apenas os veículos que estão com a mascara das placas `XXX-0000`. O banco só possui placas brasileiras, então outros formatos são irrelevantes.

Já tentei procurar alguma função ou até formas de fazer essa consulta no google, mas o que eu sempre acho são pessoas procurando como consultar um cpf sem mascara e por a mascara no momento da consulta. Mas eu não quero por a mascara, eu preciso filtrar os dados que já estão com essa mascara `XXX-0000`.

O banco de dados é SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O SqlServer não suporta expressões regulares por padrão, mas é possível fazer uma aproximação com o like.
Por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM PATRIMONIO WHERE NUM_PATRIMONIO LIKE '___-____'
```

Vai trazer os dados que você quer, mas não garante que só hajam letras no primeiro bloco nem que só hajam números no segundo.
Para garantir a máscara, você pode usar a sintaxe de "range":

```
SELECT * FROM PATRIMONIO WHERE NUM_PATRIMONIO LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Isto retorna o que você precisa.
A documentação do sqlserver contém alguns exemplos bem interessantes do que pode ser feito usando o like.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Muito obrigada. Era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando, e não fazia ideia do quanto era tão fácil!

Answer (score 1):

Boa Tarde,

Recomendo fazer a tratativa das mascara em alguma aplicação.

Mas caso queira diretamente no SQL tente a seguinte query:

```html
SELECT DESCRICAO_PATRIMONIO 
  FROM PATRIMONIO
 WHERE UPPER(NUM_PATRIMONIO) LIKE UPPER('HDT-2725')
```